# Facebook graph API not returning name with ads account listing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the personal ads account list. However, I get the `IDs` and `act_ids` but not the name along with them.I'm checking all the way but found no clue what's wrong i'm doing. I believe there's definitely way to get names with them as well.

I took all the reqired permissions, I believe
[image: you can check on this attached ss]
There's only `IDs` but no ad accounts name.

Comment: If you don’t specifically ask for any fields, then you will get only a very small set of default fields returned.

Comment: @CBroe You're right! I figured that out already I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not getting name because by default the api doesn't return any other informations!

You have to mention the fields to get speicifc information you need. For me i needed `name` for the ad account so what i did is this
`https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/${fb_id}/adaccounts?fields=name&access_token=${token}`

this way my result was expected one's. Although i was looking for this information speicifically but i didn't saw anywhere. Hope this will help you guys!